# How does a single server file serve concurrent requests from different users?

Tags: javascript, node.js, server

Say you have a single server file, e.g. `server.js`, that sits in a host.

The file is written to serve http `GET` and `POST` requests. When you are developing this server file in your localhost, you generate a `GET` request to test this server.

It works, the server receives the request and send something back. But what if this server file sits on a public host. What happens when multiple clients post a `GET` request to the server?

As far as the `server.js` file is concerned, it only knows that when it receives a request, it sends a reply. It doesn't care/know who sends the request and whether the reply is sent to the right client and etc. How is multiple concurrent requests dealt in real life?

- Is a copy of `server.js` created for each of the requesting clients to avoid request collisions?
- or is other techniques used?
- What determines the maximum number of concurrent requests a server can handle?

Can anyone explain this clearly please. Thanks..

Comment: "It doesn't care/know who sends the request and whether the reply is sent to the right client and etc." < your code doesn't have to do that because the `http` module does. When you do `res.send('hello')`, that `res` object (which `http` passed into your callback function!) is a unique object representing the response for that one specific request that you are currently looking at, and this way node knows what client to send the response to, since inside of this object there is also a `socket` that references the exact TCP socket over which the client connected, for example.

Comment: @ScottMarcus I think it's a NodeJS thing, so it _is_ server-side.

Comment: @ScottMarcus I would assume that the OP refers to node.js, which _does_ run on the server (especially since they referred to `server.js` which is a widely used naming convention for the entry point of the server code). The file is never downloaded, and only one instance of it runs for all clients that send a request to it, there _is_ data sharing. - And in real life, there is still no need to handle concurrent requests in a special way (unless we get into larger scale issues) because each time the request handler function is called, it has unique `req` and `res` objects.

Comment: @ScottMarcus Pretty sure they're referring to server-side JS both from the question content and the "server" tag.

Comment: "Is a copy of server.js created"...no, but potentially multiple instances of the script may be loaded into memory and executed, to serve each request. The web server takes care of this issue, not the code. As you say, the code is written to work in the context of a single request. The webserver handles all incoming requests and executes your code repeatedly, once for each new request. That's true whether the requests happen to be concurrent or not. As CherryDT mentions, it passes your code some details about which request it is serving.

Comment: @ADyson "[...] potentially multiple instances of the script may be loaded into memory and executed [...]" I'm not sure what you mean by that; it's unlikely there would be multiple copies of a single function, although obviously that'd be an implementation detail of the JS runtime. Maybe I'm misunderstanding what you're saying?

Comment: @DaveNewton I suppose what I mean is effectively you get the application executed multiple times and the majority of variables etc are reset each time - it's effectively stateless isn't it, as if it the script had never been executed before (except for things like session variables). I don't know the internals of node to know precisely how it does it but I'm thinking more conceptually - as a simple analogy, maybe like firing up 5 terminal windows simultaneously and executing the same script in them all, except with different input values to each one.

Comment: No, that's what PHP does. This is about node.js. It works like having a "click" handler in front-end JS - if you click on 5 buttons on the same page (5 requests in the same server), it still won't load your script 5 times or reset any variables or anything, it just will call your function 5 times with a different `event` object every time. Same thing here. node.js is the opposite of stateless - if you define a global variable `counter` and do `counter++` in your request handler, you just built a visitor counter (albeit one that resets when the server gets restarted).

Comment: It depends. A JavaScript program written to use Express.js that runs a traditional style server on a traditional style hosting service will handle parallel requests differently to a program that runs on AWS Lambda.

Comment: Thanks a lot you guys. It's clear now, so the key is the unique `req` object that contains infos about the client. And yes, i meant `Node.js` implementation of a server. I should've stated that in the post to add clarity..